# Lists.GetByTitle(SPlist) - title differs depending on language

Tags: csom

When I ask for the list collection on a sharepoint site by

```
Dim collList As ListCollection = Web.Lists
        ctx.Load(collList)
        ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

the list "Documenten" appears in the list.

But if I want to address that list with

```
ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documenten")
```

I get the error that the list is not existing.

If I use

```
ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents")
```

it works fine...

So its a language problem.

Question: how can I use "GetByTitle" with a title as it appears in the listcollection?

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online, or version of on-prem server?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below to verify the different results:

```
Ctx.web.Lists.TryGetList(ResourceHelper.GetLocalized("Custom_List_Title", "Resources"));
```

Or

```
Ctx.web.Lists.GetByTitle(ResourceHelper.GetLocalized("Custom_List_Title", "Resources"));
```

Comment: Thx for your reply, but these gives me a "Resourcehelper is not declared" error

Comment: and: "trygetlist" is not a member of listcollection

Comment: Apparantly this problem only occurs with the "standard" library list "shared documents". This is by the way the list title that is present in the list URL: https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx. Conclusion : the list has 3 titles ...